# Populate select with database entries the oo way

Tags: php, database, oop, foreach

**My database table**

```
TABLE `dog_types` (
    `dog_type_id` int(11)
    `dog_type_name` varchar(64)
```

I would like to make the dog_type_name entries available in a select menu.
**My attempt**

```
Class Sell {
    public static function getAllDogTypes() 
    {
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT dog_type_name FROM dog_types";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array());

    // fetchAll() is the PDO method that gets all result rows
    return $query->fetchAll();
}

public static function viewSelect($name = "select") {

   $html = "<select name='$name'>\n";
   foreach ($query as $key => $val) {
       $html .= "<option value='$key'>$val</option>\n";
   }
   $html .= "</select>\n";
   return $html;
   }
}

<?php echo Sell::viewSelect(); ?>
```

**My output**

```
<select>            
    Notice: Undefined variable: query  
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()          
</select>
```

The two functions work on their own. I just cannot figure out how to put them together.
As you already guessed I am super new to all of this and would highly appreciate any kind of help!

**With noob's suggestions my code looks like this:**

```
public static function getAllDogTypes() 
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dog_types";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array());

    // fetchAll() is the PDO method that gets all result rows
    return $query->fetchAll();
}

public static function viewSelect($name = "select") {
    $query=Sell::getAllDogTypes();

    $html = "<select name='$name'>\n";
    foreach ($query as $key => $val) {
        $html .= "<option value='$key'>$val</option>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</select>\n";
    return $html;
}

<?php echo Sell::viewSelect(); ?>
```

var_dump on query shows the database entries:

```
Dog_type: array(8) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(13) "Affenpinscher" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(12) "Afghan Hound" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(4) "Aidi" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(16) "Airedale Terrier" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(6) "Akbash" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(5) "Akita" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(13) "Alano Espanol" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2) { ["dog_type_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["dog_type_name"]=> string(16) "Alaskan Klee Kai" } }
```

**The error messages**

> Notice: Undefined variable: query 
>   Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: That is because you are not passing `$query` variable to the `viewSelect` function. It is defined in `getAllDogTypes` but not in `viewSelect`

Comment: Aha! Thank you! How would I pass the $query variable on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line to at the beginning  of second function:

$query=Sell::getAllDogTypes(); //get the value of $query from getAlldogTypes function which is present in this class.

$query returns array of objects, so you need a nested foreach loop

```
$html = "<select name='$name'>\n";
foreach ($query as $obj) {
  foreach ($obj as $key=>$val)
    $html .= "<option value='$key'>$val</option>\n";
 }
}
$html .= "</select>\n";
return $html;
```

}

Comment: I am getting this error: Using $this when not in object context in

Comment: Now I am getting this: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: do a var_dump of $ query and tell me what you're getting

Comment: I updated the whole question for a better understanding! Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

first of all change

```
public static function viewSelect($name = "select",$query="") {
$sql = "SELECT dog_type_id,dog_type_name FROM dog_types";
```

Because you should pass dog_type_id in options values.

First Call this

```
 <?php $query=Self::getAllDogTypes(); ?>
```

Then call

```
 <?php echo Self::viewSelect($query); ?>
```

Comment: I get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() My foreach looks like this:  foreach ($query as $key => $val) {

Comment: For some reason I am getting this error: Undefined variable: query